# Find the GCD of all elements of set $S$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

$T$ is a set of natural numbers such that $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are its elements.

Also $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=f^2$.

Another set S contains all possible values of the product $a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f$

Find the GCD of all elements of set $S$.

No idea how to proceed.Please help.

Comment: $1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 4^2$, so $1 \in S$, so the GCD must be 1?

Comment: @kennytm How does $1$ $\in$ $S$?$S$ contains all the values of product of $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

Comment: @kennytm well the answer is 24

Comment: Ok I thought you mean $S$ contains $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$.

Comment: This makes no sense in its current form. Since there is exactly one set $T$, there is exactly one product that can be formed from its elements. It seems that what you were trying to say was that $S$ contains the products for all possible values of the product for all possible sets $T$ that satisfy the condition in the second line?

Comment: @kennytm I wouldnt have posted the question if it was that simple!!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have all of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ odd, since the squares would then all have remainder $1$ modulo $8$ and the sum wouldn't work out modulo $8$.

Thus at least two of them are even, and if only two then one of them must be divisible by $4$ or again the sum wouldn't work out modulo $8$. It follows that the product is divisible by $8$.

Also at least one of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ must be divisible by $3$ since otherwise the squares would all have remainder $1$ modulo $3$ and the sum wouldn't work out modulo $3$. It follows that the product is divisible by $3$, and thus by $24$.

Since the example given in a comment yields a product of $24$, this is the desired $\gcd$.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation.

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2=x_6^2$$

Take advantage of this decision.

$$x_1=2sp$$

$$x_2=2kp$$

$$x_3=2tp$$

$$x_4=2bp$$

$$x_5=b^2+t^2+k^2+s^2-p^2$$

$$x_6=b^2+t^2+k^2+s^2+p^2$$

Using this method you can write the same formula, for any number of summands.  It remains to write the product and to factor.